# No suitable application records were found

Tags: ios, ios4, app-store

I created an App Store archive file. During validation it raises an error with the following message

> Please make sure that you have set up a record for this application on iTunes Connect.

Comment: Is there any resolution to this problem?  I'm faced with the same issue.

Answer (score 164):

I've just been through the same problem and resolved it quite easily.

Through iTunes Connect the app has to be in the state of 'waiting for upload'. At first I thought 'prepare for upload' was sufficient but not so. Thus you need to go through the questions about have you changed encryption and how you want the new version released etc.

Once you've been through this section of Connect then the app is in the correct status of 'waiting for upload.' My validation of my app then just went straight through.

Comment: May I add to this that once your app is ready, there will be a blue button in the top-right of the app screen that says "Ready for Upload" - I'd never seen that there before! So I clicked on it, clicked yes to all the legal stuff and boom, "Prepare for upload" changed to "Waiting for upload". All is now right with the world. :)

Answer (score 49):

To be more precise.  Here's how you move your app to the "Waiting for Upload" status...

Starting from the "Manage Your Apps" window in iTunes Connect, click the big icon for your app.

That will bring you to the "App Information" and "Versions" window.

In the Versions section click the View Details button.

In this next window there should be a button on the top right that says something like "Upload Binary."  Click that button.

There's where you answer about encryption.  Answer those questions about encryption and your app should be moved to the Waiting for Upload status.

Go back to the App Information Versions window.  It should say "Waiting for Upload" in the Versions section.

Nowadays you will be informed specifically if you have a Bundle ID mismatch when you try to do the upload from your Xcode organizer.  It'll even tell you which Bundle ID you have in iTunes Connect and which Bundle ID your app has.

Comment: the response above this one is correct, but Joe C was more precise and the steps are helpful to achive the goal of solving the error/issue.

Answer (score 10):

That error indicates that either there is no application in your iTunes Connect account with the bundle id of your application, or the application that is there is not in the "waiting for upload" state.

Answer (score 2):

There is one other explanation for this. You are validating with wrong email/password. It can easily happen when you are working for more clients.