# Validating an existing app in App Store

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an existing app in the App Store (Version 1.0). I'm trying to change the displayed title of the app in the App Store. The only to do this, apparently, is to update the binary and edit the title, subject to app review.

So I go into Xcode and change the version number (I've tried bumping up the Build number, as well as the Version number). I do the archive, but when it comes to validating the archive, it tells me "No suitable application records were found."

What gives??

Comment: possible duplicate of [No suitable application records were found.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858260/no-suitable-application-records-were-found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that

1. Changing the name did not changed the bundle id.
2. You're in Waiting to Upload mode.

Answer (score 1):

> - Ensure an application record exists for your application in iTunes    Connect.
> - Ensure the application record status is at least Waiting to    Upload.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-archives_organizer/articles/validating_and_publishing_applications.html) (Apple Documentation)

Comment: I went to iTunes Connect, and Add Version, and specified Version 1.1. Xcode built Version 1.1, too. But I still get the same error message when I validate. The application record is definitely there, and it says "Prepare to Upload".