# iOS: issue submitting app on 2nd attempt

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

So I submitted my app and it got rejected due to a missing icon. I fixed that, archived and went to validate again but now get this message:

```
No suitable application records were found.
Please make sure that you have set up a record for this application on iTunes Connect.
```

I havent changed anything in my app except the name of one of the icons. I'm not sure whats happening. Can anyone give me some advice?

Ta

Comment: possible duplicate of [No suitable application records were found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858260/no-suitable-application-records-were-found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found out why its occuring. Currently in iTunes Connect that app is under the status 'Binary Rejected'. You must change it back to 'Waiting for upload'.

This question has it more thoroughly explained and the 2nd answer has steps:

[No suitable application records were found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858260/no-suitable-application-records-were-found)