# Xcode: No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier is correct

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm having a strange issue when trying to upload my ios app, it was working perfectly fine 24 hours ago but when attempting to upload, it will not go.

I am admin on the developer and app store connect accounts. The app has existed for a few years so it's not a new app, the bundle id matches correctly and I have all proper provisioning profiles and certificates.

This issue makes zero sense since less than 24 hours ago I was able to upload the app just fine.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It seems to affect only company accounts, individual developers seem to be fine.

Comment: @Demosthese actually, we manage a few company accounts and noticed that some are uploading normally and this one in particular is not accepting new build uploads on any of its apps.

Comment: Try these. Same question asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858260/no-suitable-application-records-were-found

Answer (score 3):

It seems like this problem may be related to Apple making some changes to user roles in iTunes connect. Using an admin account to remove and re-add your permissions for your app may fix it.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/324473#324473

Comment: Exactly same i have faced and its because my apple id have not access to that app ..But uploaded successfully when i logged with admin account. Thanks @peter